# Implement (almost) fully featured Fulltext search using PHP + mysql

Tags: php, mysql, search, mysqli, full-text-search

I'm working on a project which requires a search engine.
I'm aware of MySQL's FULLTEXT IN BOOLEAN MODE feature. But my current implementation can be simply broken by adding quotes in the text field...
What I need:
A Search engine which allows for features like `+obligatory`, `optional`, `"complete phrase"` and `-mustNotContain` and sorts the results accordingly (most matches on top etc.)

Possible solutions I think of:
a function which escapes the search string in a way, the mentioned features persist, but the MySQL won't get mad if the syntax is completely wrong.

A complete mysql-independent search algorithm written in PHP (Please tell me, if there are any libraries you would suggest) which does the same thing (and maybe allows for auto complete - completely optional)

If you were asking yourself what my current implementation is, it's currently something basic and unfinished like

```
$result = $mysqli -> query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE MATCH(TITLE) AGAINST('$q' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY MATCH(TITLE) AGAINST('$q' IN BOOLEAN MODE)")
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Writing your own search engine is very, very hard. If the full-text searching isn't adequate, try and use tools like [Elastic Search](https://www.elastic.co) or [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com). If you could write your own search engine you'd be working for Google.

Comment: I know, but before my project is finished it's easier to do so...

Comment: I know how they work it's just lazyness... I will change them when my project is about 80% finished

Comment: If this is like a typical software project then after the first 80% you'll have the other 80% to go. Do try and evaluate the direction now before you're over-committed on a non-viable path.

Answer (score 3):

You really want to use mysqli::prepare instead of interpolating the search string into the query (see http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php). The result should look something like this.

```
$statement = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE MATCH(TITLE) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY MATCH(TITLE) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE)");
$statement->bind_param("ss", $q, $q);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->get_result();
```

The statement is first prepared and then parameters are bound to the question mark placeholders. No manual escaping is required.

Comment: Thought about using that. Unfortunately, this isn't fixing all problems. For example, the string `+-` causes the query to not work, because this isn't some sort of SQL injection, but a syntax error in the MATCH against syntax

Comment: Ah, I see, if I understand http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-boolean.html correctly, quoting the phrase containing the +, - etc with double quote should work. Were is $q comming from? Does it contain one word or multiple?

Comment: $q is in my case the $_GET['q'] variable by an HTML form textfield aka raw user input

Comment: So it is just the words the user entered and you want to find all rows that match any word or all words? In any case, splitting the string into words, quoting each word with double quotes and escaping any double quotes within the word should work.

Comment: But in this case i lose the ability to require specific search terms...

Comment: Could you please give examples for $q (and when appropriate explain what you expect as result?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127967/discussion-between-martin-and-roiex).